# how to make an input field appear according to the number we have selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Hello I would like to know how I could do to make appear an input field according to the number that I would have selected.
For example:
I selected the 5 and 5 input fields would appear below the select
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you means something like this?

html:

```
<select id="sel1">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div id="sel2">

</div>
```

js (using jquery):

```
<script>
$("#sel1").change(function(){
  $("#sel2 input").remove();

  var inputs = $(this).val();
  for(var i=0; i<inputs; i++){
        $("#sel2").append("<input type='text' />")
  }
});
</script>
```

live fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ams6vdcn/

Comment: Thanks for helping me